# What is the Support for a homeomorphisms' composition?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, manifolds, lie-groups

I was reading this article about Homeo group:
https://www.ams.org/journals/notices/202104/noti2252/noti2252.html?adat=April%202021&trk=2252&galt=feature&cat=feature&pdfissue=202104&pdffile=rnoti-p482.pdf

All functions are homeomorphisms from the group Homeo(M) for some non compact manifold M.
$f, g \in Homeo_c(M)$ the identity component.
$B \subset M$ an open ball.

I yellow highlighted the important assumptions and **ultimately want to understand what is red highlighted**. 
$i.e.$ I'd like to know how the support of the composition of this homeomorphisms work.

Rather than an explanation of this particular case (which would be highly appreciated too), **I'd like to know where I can study this stuff because I'm really lost** at calculating the support for the conjugate $ga^{-1}g^{-1} \;$ and so on.

Thank you in advance.

[image: Ultimately I want to understand what is red highlighted.]

Here is some additional info, **we have property 2 and want to prove property 3.**

"**1. Fragmentation.** Let $\mathcal{O}$ be an open cover of $M$. Then $\operatorname {Diff}_c(M)$ and $\operatorname {Homeo}_c(M)$ are generated by homeomorphisms supported on elements of $\mathcal{O}$.

**2. Localized perfectness.** Let $B$ be an open ball in $M$. Any element of $\operatorname {Diff}_c(B)$ or $\operatorname {Homeo}_c(B)$ can be written as a product of commutators.

**3. Simplicity of the commutator group.** Let $g \neq id$ in $\operatorname {Diff}_c(M)$, and let $B \subset M$ be an open ball. Then any commutator in $\operatorname {Diff}_c(B)$ lies in the normal closure of $g$. The same holds replacing $\operatorname {Diff}$ with $\operatorname {Homeo}$.

While I have deliberately stated these in parallel for Diff and Homeo, the proofs of 1 and 2 are entirely different in the smooth and $C^0$ case. Fragmentation is easy for diffeomorphisms: an element of $\operatorname {Diff}_c(M)$ is always the time-one map of a compactly supported time dependent vector field, and cutting that vector field off by smooth bump functions is the only tool required for fragmentation."

**This article didn't define support.**

Comment: As written this doesn’t make sense without more context. A function is said to have support on a set $A$ if it is zero outside of $A$, more or less. But a homeomorphism can only be zero once. What does support mean?

Comment: @FShrike  In the description I put the whole article which didn't define support.

I'm editing the post to add more info.

Comment: The support of a self-homeomorphism $f : X \to X$ is the smallest closed subset $C \subset X$ such that $x \not\in C \implies f(x)=x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Lemma** 
Let $f,g \in Homeo(M)$ be self-homeomorphisms, M a Manifold. 
With supports $supp(f) = A$ and $supp(g) = B$, respectively. 
Accordingly with the definition given by @Lee Mosher. 
Let $\beta \in M - (A \cup B)$, then
$fg(\beta) = f(\beta) = \beta$ 
Therefore $supp(fg) \subset A \cup B$

If we assume $A \cap B = \emptyset$, we can guarantee $A \cup B = supp(fg)$: 
Let $\alpha \in A \cup B$ 
*Case 1)* $\alpha \in A$ $\subset M - B$ 
$fg(\alpha) = f(\alpha) \neq \alpha $, then $\alpha \in supp(fg)$ 
*Case 2)* $\alpha \in B$ $\subset M - A$ 
$fg(\alpha) = f(\alpha') \;\;\;$ for some $\alpha' \neq \alpha$ 
$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; = \alpha' \;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ Since g is injective, necessarily $\alpha' = g(\alpha) \in B$ 
then $\alpha \in supp(fg)$ 
Therefore $A \cup B \subset supp(fg)$

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \square$

**Now for my particular question:** 
As $f = aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ with $a, b \in Homeo(M)$ and $supp(f) = B$, 
then $\;supp(a) = ba^{-1}b^{-1}(B)$ 
$\therefore \;supp(a) = a(supp(a)) = aba^{-1}b^{-1}(B) = f(B) = B\;\;\;$ since a and f are injective.

Notice $\;supp(a) = supp(a^{-1})$ since a is self-homeomorphism. 
Let $\alpha \in M-B$, then $ga^{-1}g^{-1}(g(\alpha)) = ga^{-1}(\alpha) = g(\alpha)$ 
Therefore $supp(ga^{-1}g^{-1}) \subset g(B)\;$ since g is bijective.

Let $\beta \in B$, then $ga^{-1}g^{-1}(g(\beta)) = ga^{-1}(\beta) = g(\beta')$ with $\beta' \neq \beta$ and since g is injective, $g(\beta') \neq g(\beta)$ 
Therefore $g(B) \subset supp(ga^{-1}g^{-1})$ 
$\therefore supp(ga^{-1}g^{-1}) = g(B)$

As $B \cap g(B) = \emptyset$, by **Lemma:** 
$supp([a,g]) = supp(aga^{-1}g^{-1}) = B \cup g(B)$

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \square$

If you find any errors, feel free to let me know. Thank you.